# Shortcut for clike languages comments not working/implemented?

Tags: codemirror, adobe-brackets

I'm using [the Brackets code editor](http://brackets.io/)  to code in C++ and I'm having a hard time having the shortcut for `lineComment` and `blockComment` working...

The shortcuts are `[Ctrl+/]` and `[Ctrl+Shift+/]`, they work perfectly for CSS, JS.. etc but not with C++ files.

I looked into the `clike.js` file in the [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) folder of [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), the `blockCommentStart`, `blockCommentEnd` and `lineComment` are correctly defined.

Is it a known issue? has anyone found a workaround?
Before that,I was coding with Notepad++ and this feature was the one I used the most. It's really hard not to have it anymore

Answer (score 0):

You said you saw that `blockCommentStart`, `blockCommentEnd` and `lineComment` are correctly defined in `clike.js`. From CodeMirror documentation

> This file defines, in the simplest case, a lexer (tokenizer) for your
>   language—a function that takes a character stream as input, advances
>   it past a token, and returns a style for that token. More advanced
>   modes can also handle indentation for the language.

It is used to highlight the c++ file. But also it could be used to auto comment line with shortcut. However it is probably not implemented for C++. For this feature comment addon from CodeMirror might be used http://codemirror.net/addon/comment/comment.js since `The addon also defines a toggleComment command, which will try to uncomment the current selection, and if that fails, line-comments it.`

Answer (score 0):

This was a [Brackets bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/7764), but it was fixed in the Sprint 39 release.

(Fwiw though, language metadata in Brackets is defined in a file called [languages.json](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json) - although Brackets extensions [can add to / modify](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support#defining-a-new-language) this metadata as well).